# ajax link inside an ajax form calls form submission for no reason rails 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form of following structure

ROR code"

```
form_tag class='remote_form' remote=>true
{
some fields
1
2
3
one <a> link remote=>true
4
submit button
}
```

jquery code

```
$('.remote_form').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, elements){
do some blah blah
}
```

now when I click "one  link" "blah blah" thing executes . why is that so ?
basically only when I click submit "blah blah" must get executed.

Have I done anything wrong ?

---

My idea :
The form contains a few elements . and before the form gets submitted I need to do a few things so I use ajax:before send for remote_form . Now I also have some  link which is an ajax request totally independent of form.
Obviously the one  link shouldn't cause the execution of "blah blah "..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand. Your problem is that the callback is fired although the form hasn't been submitted ?

Did you try with the classic $.ajax() function :

```
$('.remote_form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(){
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: inside my beofresend I can return false to stop my form from being sent. But in this I can't do so. :(

Comment: Hmmm... do you really want your form to be sent by AJAX ? In this case, you'll always **return false;** at the end of the submit() event — and then call a function (eg. submitForm() which manually submit your form data) in the beforeSend() callback. Am I clear ? :o)

Comment: Thank you for your response . But this is not possible in my case .
since the form makes an ajax call via rails-ujs.js (remote-data=true).

Answer (score 1):

ajax:beforeSend is meant for all ajax calls. That's why the function was getting executed. if you want the function to be executed only on form submit, bind that function to form's submit event like

```
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    });
```

But jquery has a plugin which can do all these things for you. I think you should have a look at the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit) which explains everything about submitting a form using ajax.

Comment: okay it might be that "ajax:beforeSend" is meant for all ajax call but what if I want to do it only for from. ? I don want to mess with rails-ujs.js .